# High cpu usage by Spyder even when idle

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

When I start Spyder it launches OK and generally performs fine except that even when it is doing nothing (e.g. straight after launching) it constantly uses 50% of my CPU and continues to do so indefinitely as seen in this [task manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMd67.png).

If I right click on the highlighted python line in the screenshot and select 'end task', the over all CPU usage reduces to ~ 2% and Spyder appears to continue working. So there is a work around but I'd prefer to not have to do this every time I start Spyder. Specs as follows:

- Spyder 3.2.
- 8
- Python 3.5.4
- Windows 10
- 2 Cores, 4 logical processors
- Intel Core i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50 GHz 2.71 GHz
- Memory 32 GB

Any idea on how I can stop this from happening?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Could you make your Task manager to report the full command that each process is running? That way we could see what that Python process you need to kill is trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: I have to split this over two comments:

Comment: "C:\winpython-64bit-3.5.4.0qt5\python-3.5.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin\QtWebEngineProcess.exe" --type=renderer --disable-gpu-memory-buffer-video-frames --enable-threaded-compositing --no-sandbox --use-gl=desktop --primordial-pipe-token=33618F9101FE6B845BFDF7E37F1A23EE --lang=en-US --enable-pinch --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=2 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --content-image-texture-target=0,0,3553;0,1,3553;0,2,3553;0,3,3553;0,4,3553;0,5,3553;0,6,3553;0,7,3553;0,8,3553;0,9,3553;0,10,3553;0,11,3553;0,12,3553;0,13,3553;0,14,3553;0,15,3553;1,0,3553;1,1,3553;1,2,3553;

Comment: 1,3,3553;1,4,3553;1,5,3553;1,6,3553;1,7,3553;1,8,3553;1,9,3553;1,10,3553;1,11,3553;1,12,3553;1,13,3553;1,14,3553;1,15,3553;2,0,3553;2,1,3553;2,2,3553;2,3,3553;2,4,3553;2,5,3553;2,6,3553;2,7,3553;2,8,3553;2,9,3553;2,10,3553;2,11,3553;2,12,3553;2,13,3553;2,14,3553;2,15,3553;3,0,3553;3,1,3553;3,2,3553;3,3,3553;3,4,3553;3,5,3553;3,6,3553;3,7,3553;3,8,3553;3,9,3553;3,10,3553;3,11,3553;3,12,3553;3,13,3553;3,14,3553;3,15,3553 --service-request-channel-token=33618F9101FE6B845BFDF7E37F1A23EE --renderer-client-id=8 --mojo-platform-channel-handle=4580 /prefetch:1

Comment: Thanks. As you can see, that's not related to Spyder directly. This could be related to your graphics card driver, at least we've found similar problems are. I think your only alternative to workaround this issue is to use Anaconda instead, with PyQt 5.6, which doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Above is the QT web engine process, this is the python process highlighted in the picture. Also if I end this process, the above process also ends along with it: c:\winpython-64bit-3.5.4.0qt5\python-3.5.4.amd64\pythonw.exe c:\winpython-64bit-3.5.4.0qt5\python-3.5.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyder_terminal\server\main.py --port 8071 --shell C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe

Comment: I see. So a better fix to what I described above is to uninstall the `spyder-terminal` package.

Comment: OK, I have been thinking of switching to Anaconda. I don't know a lot about the different distributions but is Anaconda recommended for use with Spyder rather than WinPython?

Comment: I think we are a little out of sync with comments, I keep posting and not realizing that you have! I'll try that and see how it goes. Thanks for your help with this

Comment: We're answering almost at the same time! So, please my last advice and let me know how that goes.

Comment: I removed spyder-terminal (with pip) and relaunched Spyder. Problem fixed! Thanks for that. Should I still think about swapping to Anaconda?

Comment: Two things: 1. Please mark my answer as correct, so that other people can see that if they look for a similar problem. Second, Anaconda is better maintained (a company is behind it). Unfortunately, WinPython is (almost) a one man job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) After talking with the OP, we discovered this problem was caused by `spyder-terminal`. Therefore, removing that package fixes it.

Comment: I'm having an issue with high CPU usage and high latency when typing and saw your comment elsewhere about running `spyder --debug-info verbose`.  When I do this, I'm getting a lot of messages about completion plugins and responses, even if I disable completion/kite in preferences.  Also no performance improvement running without Anaconda.  Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, I'm using Catalina.  Downgrading to 4.1.5 appears to largely fix the problem (a tiny bit of latency still there but it's manageable).